# Difference between service container and constructor injection

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

As I understand laravel's service container is for dependency injection.

I usually did these injections by `use ClassName` and constructor in a given class.

Why would I use service container instead?

After spending all day on reading about it I do not see the difference.

Comment: By doing `use ClassName` you're not injecting anything, you're only helping PHP find the target class when you do `new ClassName`. Namespaces have nothing to do with dependency injection in this context. Read [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) carefully.

Comment: @AlexKarshin Sounds like I am confusing something. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

If you are type hinting dependencies in controllers constructor you are already using dependency injection and Laravel service container.

There are a lot of good articles and docs about Laravel service container and dependency injection.

I recommend these:

[Another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130862/8384864)

[Laravel Docs Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container)

[Laravel Docs Dependency Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)

Comment: I have been reading all day about Service Containers. Looks like I did not understand correctly what dependency injection actually was. Thank you for linking this

Comment: No, problem. It is one of the advanced things so you should take some time to fully understand how Laravel service container works, step by step

Answer (score 0):

PHP type-hinting is not specifically bound to the dependency injection, it's just a PHP feature which allows it thanks to API reflection.

There is at least 1 thing you can't do except via constructor: the contextual binding.

And another one which can't be done via constructor: partial resolution (i.e. `app(Test::class, ['arg2' => 'test'])`

Also notice that dependency injection can work on every method, not only constructor (e.g. `app()->call([$this, 'injectedMethod'])` )

Finally, you should read this doc which explains very clearly everything the container is able to.

https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/bd857d9b0ac895df7604dd2e63b23afe